# Istanbul / nyc code coverage issues

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I'm using ExpressJS and have created unit tests with mocha along with coverage using istanbul nyc. I have implemented a route (see code below) and am verifying code coverage of my tests.

The following registers as 100% covered,

```
import express from 'express';
import controller from './controller';

export default express
  .Router()
  .get('/', (req, res) => controller.all(req, res));
```

But the following registers at 0% coverage:

```
import express from 'express';
import controller from './controller';

export default express
  .Router()
  .get('/', controller.all);
```

Both work and both pass unit tests. The second, IMO,  'should' also register at 100% covered.

Any ideas how to make the second version register? And why it doesn't work as is?

Note: I'm using mocha for my tests. The logic above is not the test logic, but logic that is ultimately invoked by my test